# golang regex to remove in-field doublequote in csv file

Tags: regex, csv, go

ive been trying to remove in field quotes of my csv file with regex, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work. heres my code:

```
input2, err := ioutil.ReadFile("input.csv")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

output2 := bytes.Replace(input2, []byte("[^;]\"|\"[^;]"), []byte(""), -1)

if err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.csv", output2, 0666); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

In my case, I just wanted to remove all doublequotes that doesnt have a semicolon before or after, but so far it isnt replacing anything in the file.

Comment: Try ``regexp.MustCompile(`("?;"|";"?)|"`).ReplaceAll(input2, []byte("${1}"))``

Comment: You should parse your CSV file with package encoding/csv which will automatically remove the double quotes needed to quote CSV stuff. Then you can do any transformation of each field record safely.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works so far and got me a step forward thanks! however i diddnt think about the first and last doublequote on each line doesnt have a semicolon next to it -.- gotta figure that out and post the solution after.

Volker ive been trying to do that last week, but it always gave me an error because of those infield doublequotes, or maybe ive just been too stupid.

Comment: Do you mean "the first and last doublequote on each line" should not be removed? Just use `(^"|"$|"?;"|";"?)|"` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
output2 := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(^"|"\r?$|";")|"`).ReplaceAll(input2, []byte("${1}"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2eKirl/11)

The pattern matches

- `(?m)` - multiline flag that makes `^` match start of line and `$` end of line positions (note: `$` in the multiline mode only matches before LF, `\n`, not before CR, `\r`!)
- `(^"|"$|";")` - Capturing group 1 (its value is referred to with `${1}` from the replacement pattern):

  - `^"|` - a `"` at the start of a line or
  - `"\r?$|` - a `"` at the end of a line or
  - `";"` - a `"`, then `;"`, then `"`
- `|` - or
- `"` - a `"` in any other context.

Comment: ^"| does remove the first doublequote for whatever reason, in the regex demo it seems to work, but in my file its removed.
"?\n" does work for me,
but after testing with different files ive noticed that sometimes i have 2 doublequotes at the end of the string which should be untouched. still testing around but thanks four your answers so far, theyve really helped me alot.

Comment: im still kinda confused still. i figured `(?m)` is needed for multiline for `^"` to work. `"$` does nothing or it also accepts a `";"`at the end when it should be `";""`. 
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/2eKirl/9) shows it should work, but in the csv i still always lose the 2nd doublequote at the end of each line

Comment: @Max1899 I believe if it is due to the CRLF endings, use ``(?m)(^"|"\r?$|"?;"|";"?)|"``

Comment: ok that was the issue, thanks! but just for understanding: why do you use `"?;"|";"?` ?
if i interpret it correctly the ? operator means optional, but if i aint wrong in the middle of each csv line its always `"`at the end of each field, `;`as field seperator and `"`at the beginning of the field. the only exceptions are the single `"`at the begining and the double `""` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing CSV files, you are best of using the encoding/csv package.